# How much time SnowPipe keeps track of files that has being already loaded

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've created a SnowPipe to load continuos data from an S3 Bucket. In the S3 Bucket I have the data compressed in parquet files, but time to time maybe this data is loaded again and it is replacing the old parquet file with the new one (when the data is re-loaded the parquet file takes the same name).

Ideally I would like to re-ingest this parquet file in my table with SnowPipe, but I've been checking that SnowPipe keeps track of the files that has already being loaded based only on the name in the file and doesn't check if the data changes. So my new parquet file with the same name won't be reloaded.

- How long SnowPipe is keeping track of this loaded files? The documentation said that the copy history of SnowPipe is available for 14-days, but I'm not sure if this is the same as the loaded files.
- Do you have any idea on a workaround to solve this issue? It is important that the parquet file has the same name to keep the S3 Bucket as clean as possible and not stored duplicates there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the pipe object will not reload the same filename if it was loaded within the last 14 days.

Workarounds if changing the name is really not an option:

Schedule the recreation of the pipe, using create or replace, this will drop the metadata of loaded files. The existing event notification and integration with S3 will not need to be changed assuming there are no other changes.

Or, don't use Snowpipe, use copy into with force=true to reload files that have already been loaded. You could schedule this with a task.